# Parent and children communicate via a service in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-services, angular-components

Pass data from app component to router-outlet render component with Sharing service, I can passing string and another data but I want to know How can I get data from my api and share for component.
(cant use get Method Because my component render and I cant refresh it)

in appcomponent i have checkbox for category of book and user when check new item call ChangeMessage and send Categoryid id then in ChangeMessage method update books and share to another component for show:

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class DataService {
  private Messagesource = new Subject<any>();
  curentMessage$ = this.Messagesource.asObservable()
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') public url: string) { }
  ChangeMessage(message: any) {
    let result = this.http.get<Book[]>(this.url + 'api/Books');
    this.Messagesource.next(result);
  }
}
```

in another component, get list of book and update list:

```
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {

  booklist: Book[]
  constructor(public service:CategoryServic,private ds:DataService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.ds.curentMessage$.subscribe(x => this.booklist2 = x)
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe what's wrong with the following lines of code

```
let result = this.http.get<Book[]>(this.url + 'api/Books');
```

It is to be noted first that the above method would return result as an Observable, and as per your code requirements you must pass a variable of type `Book[]` not an observable, to the argument of the next method. Also, if you are using `HttpClient` the get call won't be made unless you subscribe to the result. To further understand this let's look at what angular documentation says about http client methods ([see here](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request)):

An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.

Apart from that, I usually take the approach to initialize the constructor of the `Subject` with some default value, this might make you relate better. For example, let's say if I were to maintain a variable that keeps the state of weather the user has logged in, I would initialize my subject as:

```
 private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```